# How to open native youtube app from a video embedded in web page

Tags: ipad, mobile-safari, youtube

when I view a page on my iPad and there is a YouTube video embedded, if I click it I can watch it directly within safari.
This way, though, I cannot favorite the video, I cannot know the title of it or share it. Only thing I can do is watch it.

I'd like to be able to open the link to video in native youtube app, or at least open the YouTube web page of that video.

Is there a way to do it?

Answer (score 1):

The following applies to IOS 8 on iPhone:
A YouTube logo appears in the lower right corner of embedded YouTube videos.

If you click on the usual big round 'play button' in the center of the embedded video, it will play fullscreen inside Safari. However if you click on the YouTube logo, the video will open in the YouTube app.

Answer (score 0):

There's a way in iOS 5, but I don't know what happens in iOS 6 and 7, after they removed the YouTube app…

In iOS 5, at the top of the video is the video's title. That title is a hyperlink — tapping it opens the video in the iOS 5 YouTube app.